# Displaying an object's variable values that are not equal to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem figuring out how to display my object's stats that are not equal to 0.  Basically I have an Item class that contains 50+ variables like strength, agility, intelligence, etc... all defaulted to equal 0.  Every time I click a button, it generates an object and gives some of the object's attributes non-zero values (aka strength is now 3, agility is now 2, everything else stays 0).

In my GUI script, upon clicking the generated item I wanted it to display the item's details.  I just want it to display the object's attributes if they were not 0.  That way I don't have 50+ lines of attributes on the item saying it's just of value 0.

A snippet of the item's details is below(Note it compiles and runs fine):

```
public void LootDetailWindow(int id)
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 15, 150, 80), "<color=white><size=15>" + item.Name + "</size></color>");
    GUI.Label(new Rect (10, 50, 100, 100), item.Icon);
    GUI.Label (new Rect (150, 50, 200, 100), "Level Requirement: " + item.Reqlvl.ToString() + "\nSell Value: " + item.Value);

    //here I want to create a label that for every value that is not 0, to display it.
}
```

So how would I go about going through each attribute and checking to see if it's 0?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(int)) continue;

    int val = (int)prop.GetValue(obj);
    if(val != 0) Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I largely agree with the above but also consider..
you have a class with 50+ int fields, most are 0 blah blah
at least consider that that class might be better of being replaced by a dictionary if you're going to *tend* to be enumerating its fields, or are likely to add new attributes reguarly, ie

```
enum attributeTypes
{
    strength,
    agility,
    ...
}
```

and replace your hardcoded fields with a

```
Dictionary<attributeTypes, int>
```

since you want them to default to 0 this will probably work nicely

*might not* be a good idea of course depending on context but could be...

Answer (score 1):

You can [make a custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx), decorate the members you're interested in with that attribute, then [use reflection to iterate over the members that have your custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168942/how-do-i-get-the-member-to-which-my-custom-attribute-was-applied).

Reflection is relatively slow, so remember to [cache the list of conforming members after the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616554/is-reflection-really-that-slow-that-i-shouldnt-use-it-when-it-makes-sense-to).

When you have your list of members, you can get their names [and actual values for your current object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and perform your presentation logic.